Issues with Mobile Responsive Design in Magento 2 PageBuilder
I’m experiencing a problem with Magento 2’s PageBuilder while creating CMS pages. The mobile view displayed in the PageBuilder editor looks correct, but the pages don’t appear as expected on actual mobile devices. This discrepancy suggests there might be an issue with how PageBuilder handles mobile responsiveness. Additionally, I’m finding it challenging to write custom CSS to adjust the mobile view elements. Can someone explain why PageBuilder’s mobile responsive design might not be working as intended and offer potential solutions?
I tried to fix mobile design issues by writing custom CSS to match the PageBuilder editor's preview. However, I struggled to create effective CSS rules and the live mobile view still doesn’t align with the editor’s design. The discrepancies suggest that the PageBuilder’s mobile responsiveness might not be working correctly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
